# Sign XML file with my .PEM certificate using NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, xml, certificate, x509certificate

I need to sign an XML file with my .PEM certificate and password using NODEJS. The expected result will be an XML output file with the following format:

```
<Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
  <SignedInfo>
    <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
    <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
    <Reference URI="">
      <Transforms>
        <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
        <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
      </Transforms>
      <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
      <DigestValue>zHZj0KS0h60yrhNIijxk0HgKEQI=</DigestValue>
    </Reference>
  </SignedInfo> 
  <SignatureValue>e6ENjwpibfoCkWL13X......</SignatureValue>
  <KeyInfo>
     <X509Data>
        <X509Certificate>BaWgAwIBAgIIUgD9d3AI..</X509Certificate>
     </X509Data>
  </KeyInfo>
</Signature>
```

But I'm not able to add this tag `<X509Certificate>` and its values.
My output xml file is something like this:

```
<Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
  <SignedInfo>
    <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
    <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
    <Reference URI="">
      <Transforms>
        <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
        <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
      </Transforms>
      <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
      <DigestValue>zHZj0KS0h60yrhNIijxk0HgKEQI=</DigestValue>
    </Reference>
  </SignedInfo> 
  <SignatureValue>e6ENjwpibfoCkWL13X......</SignatureValue>
  <KeyInfo>
     <X509Data>
        </X509Certificate>
     </X509Data>
  </KeyInfo>
</Signature>
```

Check below my code in Node.js v16.0.3:

```
var select = require('xml-crypto').xpath
  , dom = require('xmldom').DOMParser
  , SignedXml = require('xml-crypto').SignedXml
  , FileKeyInfo = require('xml-crypto').FileKeyInfo
  , fs = require('fs')
    
    function signXml(xml, xpath, key, dest) {
      var sig = new SignedXml()
      sig.signingKey = fs.readFileSync(key)
    
      // not working:
      sig.canonicalizationAlgorithm = "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"
      sig.signatureAlgorithm = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"
      sig.addReference(xpath, ["http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature", "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"])
    
      // working:
      // sig.addReference(xpath)
    
      sig.computeSignature(xml)
      fs.writeFileSync(dest, sig.getSignedXml())
    }
    
    function MyKeyInfo() {
        this.getKeyInfo = function(key) {
            return "<X509Data></X509Data>"
        };
        this.getKey = function(keyInfo) {
            return fs.readFileSync("certificate.pem", 'utf-8');
        };
    }
    
    //formatando nota fiscal
    var xml = '<ns1:ReqConsultaNotas ' +
                  'xmlns:ns1="http://localhost:8080/WsNFe2/lote" ' +
                  'xmlns:tipos="http://localhost:8080/WsNFe2/tp" ' +
                  'xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ' +
                  'xsi:schemaLocation="http://localhost:8080/WsNFe2/lote http://localhost:8080/WsNFe2/xsd/ReqConsultaNotas.xsd">' +
                '<Header Id="Consulta:notas">' +
                  '<Version>1</Version>' +
                '</Header>' +
              '</ns1:ReqConsultaNotas>'
    
    //sign an xml document
    signXml(xml,
      "//*[@Id='Consulta:notas']",
      "certificate.pem",
      "result.xml")
    
    console.log("xml signed succesfully")
    
    var xml = fs.readFileSync("result.xml").toString()
    
    var sig = new SignedXml();
    sig.keyInfoProvider = new MyKeyInfo();
    //sig.addReference("//*[local-name(.)='InfNfse']");
    sig.signingKey = fs.readFileSync("certificate.pem");
    sig.computeSignature(xml);
    fs.writeFileSync("signed.xml", sig.getSignedXml());
```

Any tips how to add `<X509Certificate>` tag?

Comment: How does it fail?

Comment: @MichaelKay my code doesn't generate <X509Certificate>values. Such as <X509Certificate>BaWgAwIBAgIIUgD9d3AI..</X509Certificate>

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with that too and the only solution that I could get working was adding this (you'd add it right before `sig.computeSignature(xml)` in your code):

```
sig.keyInfoProvider = {
getKeyInfo: (key, prefix) => {
    return `<X509Data><X509SubjectName>${your-cert-CN-data}</X509SubjectName><X509Certificate>${your-public-key}</X509Certificate></X509Data>`;
  },
};
```

I am hower stuck with needing `canonicalizationAlgorithm` as `c14n#` and then `xml-crypto` is not generating valid signatures...
I have switched and am trying `xmldsigjs` now instead...

Comment: did you get to make it work? Im stuck on a similar issue.

Comment: Yes, almost... See my opened issue here https://github.com/yaronn/xml-crypto/issues/230

Comment: I found a fix to it. it involved editing the xml-crypto library and ignoring the 2nd addition of transform into the signature.